# How to print /toast sum of column value in SqlLite

Tags: android, sqlite

My query is

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int cv;

            String getmont="",getyear="";

            getmont=year.getText().toString();
            getyear= (String) sid.getSelectedItem();
            SQLiteDatabase db;

            db = openOrCreateDatabase("monthapp", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            curtop = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(currentpaid)FROM monthvaluesOrgin WHERE curmonth='" + getmont + "' AND curyear='" + getyear + "'", null);
            if (curtop.moveToNext() ) {

              cv=curtop.getInt(0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cv,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }


        }
    });
```

How to print/ toast the sum value ?

It always showing EOFException

I have tried with in the try catch but not working.

Comment: How do you iterate a Cursor?

Comment: While (cursor.moveTonext)
{

}

Comment: Okay, then did you read the documentation on the cursor class `get*` methods?

Comment: Tell me how to print the sum value

Comment: `Log.d("sum", ""+cursor.getInt(0));`

Comment: Not working it shows EofException

Comment: I think you should [edit] your question with a [mcve] of your code and the full stacktrace

Comment: i have edited my question .

Comment: You forgot to add the full logcat to the question

Answer (score 0):

Assume `cursor` is your cursor returned by the `rawQuery()` call. So, use that to get int sum value:

```
int sum;
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) sum = c.getInt(0); 
else sum = -1;
c.close();
```

And then you can use `sum` whatever you want.

Comment: No I need to get sum of all values of column  in the table

May you're right but I'm not understanding 
Thanks

Comment: @sukesh but your sql code calculate sum for you. You just need to get it from the Cursor object

Comment: I tried this

Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(PAID)AS TOTAL FROM tablename where id='"+Id+"'" ,null);
While (cursor.moveTonext)
{Int sum;
sum=cursor.getInt(2);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationcontext,sum,2000).Show();

But not working

}

Comment: @sukesh but you should call cursor.getInt(0), not getInt(2). Remember, result cursor you got from rawQuery() in your case is a single row with single column.

Comment: I tried but 
But it Shows
EofException
And
Error deserializing sampled events

Comment: That also not working please see my code above

Comment: @sukesh to show int in toast you need to use String.valueOf(cv) instead of just cv.